# Why does this not compile without enable_if?

Tags: c++

Why does the following code not compile if I remove enable_if?

```
template<class T, class = typename std::enable_if<
             std::is_constructible<T, double,double,double>::value
             >::type >
operator T() const
{
    return T{x, y, z};
}
```

Example code:
with enable_if
http://ideone.com/nWdmJh

without enable_if + compile error
http://ideone.com/FBMamF

Answer (score 1):

Your `operator T()` returns a T list initialized with `x,y,z`.  This means that the overload of `DoSomething` is ambiguous between the one that takes 2 vectors or the one that takes a vector and `double*`.

So if you cast your second argument at the call site to what type it is that you want you will tell the compiler explicitly what overload to take.

The `std::enable_if` basically removes the overload that is not constructible using three `double`s, meaning it removes the ambiguity, and therefore it compiles.

Your vector is constructible with three `double`s.

```
Vector(double x, double y, double z)
```

Comment: Where's the array? Doesn't it simply pick a conversion directly do `double *` (which would fail if instantiated, but doesn't get instantiated because overload resolution already errors out earlier)?

Comment: You edited the decay out of your answer and put it back in. You shouldn't have put it back in :) Just try removing the other overload and force an implicit conversion to `double *`: it won't work. The conversion to `double *` is not possible. The only difference between with and without `enable_if` is when that gets detected.

Comment: @hvd, yea I did. Apparently I'm a bit confused.

Comment: But if the conversion to `double*` isn't possible, then how can it be ambiguous?

Comment: It's ambiguous because (roughly speaking) overload resolution happens before template instantiation. Overload resolution only pays attention to the signature. That part is not a problem if `enable_if` is not used.

Answer (score 1):

Without `enable_if`, your conversion operator exists for every type. You would get an error if attempting to instantiate the conversion operator for types that cannot be constructed from `{x, y, z}`, but that doesn't change the fact that the operator exists. Because it exists, the type is considered convertible to `double *`, and overload resolution cannot pick a best match.